# Simple Histogram plotting issue in R

Tags: r, histogram

I just starting to learn **R** and have this issue in plotting histogram:

I did sample data set below:

```
B <- c(2, 4, 5, 7, 12, 14, 16)  
hist(B) # this plots histogram
```

But when additional parameters were added like

```
hist(B, col = "red", breaks=6, xlim=c(0, max), main="My Histogram", las=2, xlab="Values")
```

Here's the error I'm getting when adding params:

> xlab = "Values") Error: unexpected ')' in "xlab = "Values")"

Appreciate any help for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the error I get when running your code. 
I get:

Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, "", ...) : invalid 'xlim' value

This is because you used "max" for your end value which is not defined in this case.  Try picking the value you want x to end at or just let the hist function pick for you.

simply remove the "xlim(1,max)" completely and it will work.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. It works after removing xlim parameter.

Comment: I'm glad that worked. If you could mark my answer as accepted that would help me out a great deal.  Thanks.